# Como fazer insert no PostgreSQL com base nos dados de um DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pandas

Estou tentando fazer um insert dos dados que possuo em um DataFrame (regastei via API GET) para uma tabela que criei no PostgreSQL. Procurei muito mas não consegui um retorno. Alguem consegue me ajudar?

Bibliotecas importadas:
import requests,
import pandas as pd,
import urllib, json e
import psycopg2

```
con = psycopg2.connect(
        user = "sa",
        password = "123",
        host = "localhost",
        database = "db",
        port = 5432
)

cur = con.cursor()

with urllib.request.urlopen("Url q vou consumir") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    #print(data)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    #regional, marca, descricaoregional, nomeoriginal, regioao, versao
    newdf = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['regional','marca_2','regional_2','nome_da_regional','norte_e_sul','versao'])



cur.close()

con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Felipe, boa noite.

Recomendo que utilize ao invés do `psycopg2` utilize o `SQLAlchemy` pois o mesmo funciona de forma integrada com o pandas tornando menos trabalhoso o processo.

Sua conexão ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://sa:123@localhost:5432/db')
```

Após a declaração da variável `newdf` você deve adicionar esse metodo do dataframe:

```
newdf.to_sql('<nome da tabela>', con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

Ele é um método que trata de todo o processo de inserção, o parâmetro `if_exists` pode ser `fail` - retorna um erro se a tabela já existir, `replace` - recria a tabela e `append` - que adiciona o conteúdo a tabela caso ela já exista.

[Caso queira saber mais sobre o método você pode acessar essa documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)